# What are the subphases of the semantics analysis compiler phase?

Tags: java, c++, c, compiler-construction

I took an interest in finding out how a compiler really works. I looked through several books and all of them agree on the fact that the compiler phases are roughly as this(correct me if I'm wrong): lexical analysis, syntax analysis, semantic analysis, intermediate code, code optimization, code generation. The lexical and syntax phases look pretty clear and straightforward as methods(but this does not mean easy of course). However, I'm still not able to find what the semantic phase really consist of. For one, I know that there should be some subphases like scope checking, declaration checking and type checking but question that has been bothering me is: are there other things that have to be done. Can you tell me what are the mandatory steps that have to taken during this phase. I know this strongly depends on the programming language and the compiler implementation but could you give me some examples concerning C/C++, Java. And could you please point me to a book/page/article where can I read those things in-depth. Thanks.

**Edit:**
The books I look through were "Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools",Aho and "Modern Compiler Design", Grune, Reeuwijk. I haven't been able to answer this question using them.  If you find this question too broad could you please give an answer considering an compiler implementation of your choice for either C,C++ or Java.

Comment: This is a really interesting question, but I think it's too broad to post here.  Different languages have different requirements in semantic analysis - for example, some languages like Scheme might not even have a semantic analysis phase and defer all checks to runtime, while other languages like Haskell have enormously complicated rules to follow during semantic analysis.  You might want to rephrase this question to be a bit more targeted so that you can get better feedback, even if that means asking several similar questions.

Comment: I had the fear that might indeed be a broad question and that's why I mentioned C/C++/Java (or imperative and object-oriented languages) as a main focus. Correct me if I'm wrong but I think that those language should share similar traits. If not do you think is still a good idea to post multiple questions for every one of them?

Comment: It is my understanding that lexical is the same thing as syntax. Are you sure that "intermediate code" is a phase?

Comment: Lexical is different from syntax. Lexical refers to tokenization (characters -> tokens) and is done by a scanner. Syntax refers to parsing (tokens -> parse tree) and is done by a parser. Of course, there do exist scannerless front-ends but even these have some notion of tokens vs. syntax categories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are typical "semantic analysis" phases that many compilers go through in one form or another.  After lexing and parsing, the following actions typically occur in this order:

- Name and type resolution.  Determines lexical scopes, identifiers declared in such scopes, the type information for those  identifiers, and for each non-declaration use of an identifier, the declaration to which it refers
- Control flow analysis.  The construction of a control flow graph over the computations explicit and/or implied (e.g., constructors) by the code.
- Data flow analysis.  Determines where variables recieve new values, and where those values are read by other parts of the program.   (This often has a local analysis done within procedures, followed possibly by one across the procedures).

Also often done, as part of data flow analysis:

- Points-to analysis.  Determination for each pointer, at each location in the code, which entities that pointer might reference
- Call graph.  Construction of a call graph across the procedures, often taking into account indirect function pointers whose estimated values occur during the points-to analysis.

As a practical matter, some of these need to be interleaved to produce better results.

Beyond this, there are many analyses used to support various optimizations and code generation passes.    If you really want to know more, consult any decent compiler book.

Comment: Can you recommend some book? Thanks.

Comment: The standard response is  "Compilers" by Aho/Ullman/Sethi, aka "the Dragon book".  Easily found at Amazon and other technical book stores.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned by templatetypedef, semantic analysis is language specific. For C++ it would among other things involve what template instantiations are required (the C++ language tends towards more and more semantic analysis), and for Java there would need to be some checked exception analysis.

Even for C the GNU C compiler can be configured to check arguments given to string-interpolations. I guess there are hundres of semi semantic analysis-related options for GCC to choose from.  If you are doing a paper on the subject, you could spend an afternoon counting them :)

Besides availability, I find that the semantic analysis is what differentiates the statically typed imperative object-oriented languages of today.

Comment: Is there somewhere a list with the things that have to be checked? Let's say for GCC.

Comment: I will not be the judge of what _has_ to be checked.  But the options you can give for GCC are found in its documentation.

Say http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/index.html#toc_Invoking-GCC

In particular, the section about warning options: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options

many of the warnings relate to the semantics of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't necessarily divide it into sub-phases at all. There are a number of things that have to be done, but at least conceptually they are all done while walking the parse tree from top to bottom and back up again. What exactly they are and how exactly it all happens depends on the language, the statement being processed, the specific compiler writer, ...

You could start to make a *list:*

1. Build symbol table.
2. Find the declarations of variables referenced.
3. Check compatibility of variable datatypes.
4. Establish subexpression types.
5. ...

You can see that already these must be somewhat intermingled in practice, rather than constitute separable sub-phases.